# Looking for a convenient way to create a "constant array"

Tags: scripting, zsh, array

In zsh, is there a convenient way to create an array of *n* copies of the same integer?

---

**Context:** In a shell script, I need to create an array, `tile_lengths`, consisting of two longish constant blocks.  A toy version of this would be something like

```
tile_lengths=(19 19 19 19 19 19 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18)
```

...except that the lengths of the blocks are typically around 50, and the values of the integers that make up each block, as well as the lengths of the blocks, are known only at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm (brand) new to zsh, so this could probably be improved:

```
tile_lengths=()
num=19
times=6
repeat $times { tile_lengths+=( $num ); ((--times)) }
num=18
times=9
repeat $times { tile_lengths+=( $num ); ((--times)) }
print $tile_lengths
```

> 19 19 19 19 19 19 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18

---

Inspired by [terdon's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285705/117549) answer, I think this is a cleaner variation of my first attempt:

```
tile_lengths=()
times=6 num=19 tile_lengths+=( $(repeat $times echo $num) )
times=9 num=18 tile_lengths+=( $(repeat $times echo $num) )
print $tile_lengths
```

> 19 19 19 19 19 19 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18

Comment: In your original version, there's no need to decrement times.  `tile_lengths=(); repeat $times tile_lengths+=($num); print $tile_lengths` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
% tile_lengths=( $(repeat 25 echo 19; repeat 30 echo 18  ) )
% echo $tile_lengths                                        
19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18
```

For other shells, you could do something like:

```
$ tile_lengths=( $(perl -le 'print "19 " x 25, "18 " x 30') )
$ print $tile_lengths
19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18
```

The first one assumes `$IFS` contains the newline character, the second that `$IFS` contains the space character, both assume `$IFS` doesn't contain `1`, `8` nor `9`. That should be the case with the default value of `$IFS`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this using only `zsh` expansions:

```bash
tl=( ${${:-{1..6}}/*/19} ${${:-{1..9}}/*/18} )
```

This takes advantage of how `zsh` performs substitutions with arrays. It creates an array filled with `1` to `n`, and then each element of the array is replaced with a constant value.

It can also use parameters that are set at runtime:

```bash
ary=()
count=3
value=7
ary+=( ${${:-{1..$count}}/*/$value} )
count=5
value=21
ary+=( ${${:-{1..$count}}/*/$value} )

typeset -p ary
# => typeset -a ary=( 7 7 7 21 21 21 21 21 )
```

In addition to the replacement expansion (`${var/pat/val}`), this uses a brace expansion (`{n..m}`) and an expansion with a constant (`${:-word}`). They are all documented in the `zshexpn` man page.

Answer (score 1):

Some more approaches:

```
tile_lengths=()
for length count (18 6 19 9) repeat $count tile_lengths+=$length
```

Using an anonymous function:

```
(){tile_lengths=(${@%.*})} 18.{1..6} 19.{1..9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeater for any shell:

```bash
shuf -rn 5 -e 19
```

Immediate values can be represented by variables.